# Revolving animation using cocos2d ios

Tags: ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone

I need a animation like revolving electrons on three orbiter path i the middle of nucleus. I am currently using cocos2d 3.2V for developing my game. I tried to make revolving animation using bezier path but this work for quadrant of circle not make a complete circle  animation. How can i achieve this kind of animation using cocos 2d?

[image: This is my sample animation]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The center is your parent node, you add the orbiting nodes to the parent with their position at an offset like 40x0, then rotate the parent and the child will rotate around it.

If you need different rotation speeds simply add multiple parent nodes to the center, one for each "planet".

If you want to make the movement an ellipsis you can cheat to some extent. You can have the parent move slightly up and down (or between any other two opposing points) synchronized with the rotation.

Comment: Do you have any sample on this kind of animation sir

Comment: Thanks for your idea... I am working on as your suggestion and also i am getting on similar kind of revolving animation